# Is there a discrepancy between createMultiFolds behavior and the resampling summary of a caret object?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I encountered a strange issue using custom folds for the cross-validation with `caret`.

A MWE (in which the use of createMultiFolds doesn't really make sense)

```
library(caret) #version 6.0-47
data(iris)

set.seed(1)    
train.idx <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .75,
                                 list = FALSE,
                                 times = 1)

train_1 <- iris[train.idx, ]

#I create specific folds
set.seed(1)    
id_1 <- createMultiFolds(train_1$Species, k=10, times = 10)

# And use them in my cross validation
cvCtrl_2 <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                         index = id_1,
                         classProbs = TRUE)

trainX <- train_1[, names(train_1) != "Species"]

# I fit my model
set.seed(1111)
rfTune2 <- train(trainX, train_1$Species,
                 method = "rf",
                 trControl = cvCtrl_2)

rfTune2
```

And my model summary is the following :

```
##Random Forest 
...
##Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 1 times)
```

`id_1` is a list of 100 index vectors, for a 10 fold cross validation repeated 10 times. And I ask `trainControl` to do the resampling using this list.

So why does my model summary define the resampling with

> (10 fold, repeated **1** times)

whereas `length(rfTune2$control$index)` is equal to 100 so I assume my model was correctly trained using all the folds ?

Should I post an issue on github or did I miss anything obvious about how trainControl work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The defaults of `trainControl` has

```
number = ifelse(grepl("cv", method), 10, 25),
repeats = ifelse(grepl("cv", method), 1, number)
```

If you supply `index`, the code has no idea what types of resampling is used. You will have to specify these arguments along with `repeats` to get the label correct.